# tcp ipv6 socket client connect failed using c language on debian10

Tags: sockets, tcp, ipv6

I wrote a simple TCP socket client with IPv6 "fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff" of my local PC, but when I connected, I said the parameter was invalid and returned 22, but I didn't know which parameter was wrong?  I run my code on debian 10. ping6 test is successful. server6 is compilation result of server.c, client6 is comilation result of client.c, server6 is normal.

```
./server6
Please wait for the client information

./client6
connect error Invalid argument errno: 22
```

1,ip addr show

```
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:1f:71:07:b3:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.108/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
...
...
```

2,ping6 test:

```
# ping6 fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff
PING fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff(fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff%enp2s0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff%enp2s0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff%enp2s0: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff%enp2s0: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff%enp2s0: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
...
...
...
```

3, client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXLINE 1024

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int socketfd;
    struct sockaddr_in6 sockaddr;
    char recvline[MAXLINE], sendline[MAXLINE];
    int n;
    
    
    socketfd = socket(AF_INET6,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    memset(&sockaddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr));
    sockaddr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sockaddr.sin6_port = htons(7770);
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff", &sockaddr.sin6_addr);


    if(connect(socketfd,(struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0 )
    {
    printf("connect error %s errno: %d\n",strerror(errno),errno);
    exit(0);
    }
   
    printf("send message to server\n");
   
    fgets(sendline,1024,stdin);
   
    if((send(socketfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0)) < 0)
    {
    printf("send mes error: %s errno : %d",strerror(errno),errno);
    exit(0);
    }
    
    close(socketfd);
    printf("exit\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

4, server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


//fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff
#define MAXLINE 1024
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int listenfd,connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in6 sockaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    int n;

    memset(&sockaddr,0,sizeof(sockaddr));

    sockaddr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sockaddr.sin6_port = htons(7770);
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::a1f:71ff:fe07:b3ff", &sockaddr.sin6_addr);
    


    listenfd = socket(AF_INET6,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr,sizeof(sockaddr));

    listen(listenfd,1024);


    printf("Please wait for the client information\n");

    for(;;)
    {
        if((connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)NULL,NULL))==-1)
        {
            printf("accpet socket error: %s errno :%d\n",strerror(errno),errno);
            continue;
         }

        n = recv(connfd,buff,MAXLINE,0);
        buff[n] = '\0';
        printf("recv msg from client:%s",buff);
        close(connfd);
    }
    close(listenfd);
}
```

Comment: For starters you could verify on both the server and client that every syscall, i.e. inet_pton, socket, bind and listen, succeeded. At the moment you don't check any of those.

Comment: On the client, the way you prepare `sockaddr` looks fine (though you may need to populate its `sin6_scope_id` as well). So, the parameter of `connect()` that is most likely invalid is if `socketfd` were `-1` indicating `socket()` failed to create an IPv6 socket, but you are not checking for that.

Comment: @freakish  yes, I find bind() failed beacause of Invalid argument.but why?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  thanks, sin6_scope_id is the answer i need.